# Status code 200 when i post data using web api in winforms C#

Tags: c#, api, web

I have a query that how can i post data using web Api in winforms application. Currently it giving me error which is below . I check web api using Postman App. It's working fine.But when i post data using winforms it returning me status code 200 and data is not inserting in database.Any help will be appreciated.

**winforms button click event**

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        try
        {
            EmployeeClass emp = new EmployeeClass() { Project_Name = "Hello", Task = "Task", Username 
              = "fazal" };
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44342/");
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values/AddTask", 
           emp).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
             {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
       
        }
```

**Here is return**

{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{  Pragma: no-cache  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?

**The Web Api controller Code is**

```
    database_access_layer.db dblayer = new database_access_layer.db();

    [HttpPost]

    public IHttpActionResult AddTask([FromBody] Taskcs css)
    { 
        try
        {
          dblayer.AddTask(css);
            return Ok("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return Ok("Something not OK ");
        }

    }
```

Comment: use ```await``` on async calls.did you step through your code and checked what actually happens when you post the data?

Comment: Yes I checked here is respone {StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{ Pragma: no-cache X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?

Comment: I mean, did it run ```dblayer.AddTask(css); ``` or not? did you use breakpoints etc?

Comment: Yes dblayer.AddTask(css); working fine !

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are expecting a type of `Taskcs` in your controller but you are sending a type of `Employee`:

```cs
    [HttpPost]

    public IHttpActionResult AddTask([FromBody] Taskcs css) <-- expects Taskcs
```

In your client:

```cs
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values/AddTask", 
           emp); <-- emp is an Employee
```

So there are two options:

1. change AddTask to expect and Employee:

```cs
public IHttpActionResult AddTask([FromBody] Employee css)
```

2. Change the client to post a Taskcs:

```cs
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values/AddTask", 
           emp.Task);
```

Comment: Can you update your code to show the changes?

Comment: I am continue to try different things . but it return status code 200 ok but data is not inserting